# steps to do to connect to oracle database from my android application

Tags: java, android, oracle

I am developing an android application. for doing it i need to connect to oracle database. i created a connection class as in Java. but when i try to run it nothing happens. i heard that a middle ware is needed to do this task. and also something about host. i didn’t get any clear ideas of what i should do. i have checked so many blogs and googling. but none helped. will somebody explain it to me in steps what all steps should i do to create my application?
please gys i am stuck here, any blogs, posts will do

```
/*imports*/



public class ConnectionClass 
{
public Connection connectToDB(){

    Connection con=null;

try{
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

 con=DriverManager.getConnection(
"jdbc:oracle:thin:@blablabla:1521:bla","usr","pass");


}catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}
return con;

}
public static void main(String arg[])
{
    try
    {
    ConnectionClass conDB=new ConnectionClass();
    System.out.println("connection*&% "+conDB );
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}

}
```

it is compiling in javac and result is obtained correctly

Comment: where's the code, where's the exception (or logCat)

Comment: that is the problem no logcat. just somethin will appear in console while running the application

Comment: How did you connect, show us some code please (usual way is to use a tier application to expose data)

Comment: It would be incredibly unwise to have a database server exposed publicly to the internet.

Comment: @BrianRoach now is my code safe?

Comment: you have to connect oracle db with jdbc?

Comment: that is the problem i dont know what should i use here, my only concern is that i need to connect to oracle db from my android application

Comment: @Mukund can u see my answer

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar yes, now which steps do i need to follow

Answer (score 2):

You can connect your oracle db or whatelse by using webservice,
I mean, you can create `webservice` on server side, You can connect `odbc` to your db in your webservice and just connect webservice with `get` and `post` method from your android app, which is more safe.

**1. Create webservice (for example in mvc4.5)**

**2. Create get or post method what you need**

**3. In your client,connect your webservice to post or get**

*For Example*

create a post method in your service like this:

```
yourserver/my_post_insert_method/name/id
```

Then in your client write a post method and give name and id parameter and then your record is written to oracle db.